# d3.json in d3-ng2-service?

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am currently upgrading a project from Angularjs and d3 v3 to Angular5 and d3-ng2-service.The new versions work together nicely and d3 works for simple examples. My challenge is: How to upgrade d3.json() to d3-ng2-service?

```
d3.json gives me the editor error: "Property 'json' does not exist on type 'typeof "d3-ng2-service"
```

Other types like d3.arc, etc. work.

My questions: 
A) Was d3.json dropped from d3-ng2-service?
B) If yes, can anybody please provide an example for replacing it by an Angular5 functionality?

Comment: I find examples for the use of d3.json() in d3.version4 like: [link](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/19ffece0a45434b0eef3cc4f973d1e3d). How would this example need to be modified to work with d3-ng2-service?

Answer (score 0):

to B) How to replace the function d3.json() within Angular2 and higher?
The function

```
d3.json('filename.json',function(error, object){let o = object});
```

creates a regular 'object' based on the structures used in the 'filename.json'-file. With the d3-ng2-service library I use instead:

```
this.http.get('filename.json').subscribe(res =>{let o = res.json()},error =>{console.log('Error'});
```

The more detailed description for loading a JSON file in Angular2 can be found in [this article](http://4dev.tech/2016/09/how-to-load-a-json-file-in-angular2/).